# MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE doesn't work

Tags: winapi

I want to make my program click specific mouse coordinates, so I am using

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, point.x, point.y, 0, 0);
```

where point.x and point.y are normalized between 0 and 65535.
However, it always clicks where the cursor is instead of the coordinates that I pass. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be missing `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` flag.

If that doesn't work - I suggest you just use `SetCursorPos()` to set the location.  Then your `mouse_move` event should work just fine.

Comment: I want to click in a different location without moving the mouse there.

Comment: @xytor You can move it back right after.  Use `GetCursorPos()`.

Answer (score 6):

simulate all the mouse events

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, point.x, point.y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to move the mouse. I want to click where the mouse is not.

Comment: @xytor in that case mouse_event is not what you want. You should instead find the window handle at the location where you want to click, and send that window a WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP event via SendMessage.